# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to serialize a command referencing a new, unsaved object(Parse.com)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am pretty new to Android, and i am trying to build an app using the database API from Parse.com. For like one week, i have the following problem when accesing the database and retrieving the object from the database:

> E/ParseCommandCache﹕ saveEventually thread had an error.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to serialize a command referencing a new, > unsaved object.
>   at com.parse.ParseCommand.resolveLocalIds(ParseCommand.java:407)
>   at com.parse.ParseCommand.onPreExecute(ParseCommand.java:306)
>   at com.parse.ParseRequest$7.then(ParseRequest.java:299)
>   at com.parse.ParseRequest$7.then(ParseRequest.java:296)
>   at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
>   at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
>   at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
>   at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
>   at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
>   at com.parse.ParseRequest.executeAsync(ParseRequest.java:296)
>   at com.parse.ParseRequest.executeAsync(ParseRequest.java:286)
>   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.maybeRunAllCommandsNow(ParseCommandCache.java:487)
>   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.runLoop(ParseCommandCache.java:597)
>   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.access$000(ParseCommandCache.java:26)
>   at com.parse.ParseCommandCache$2.run(ParseCommandCache.java:146)

Here is my code(I apologize if it is a bit messy, but i've been trying all sorts of things in the last week, and i didn't really have much time for refactoring or cleaning.):

```
package com.example.boacterapp.Pages;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class RecentSightings extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Alert alert;
    List<Alert> alerts;
    public ParseGeoPoint coordinates;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.list_view_layout);




}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RecentSightings.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AlertsClass");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;






    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alertListView);


        getDataForListView();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(RecentSightings.this,alerts);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent i = new Intent(RecentSightings.this,
                        AlertViewOnMap.class);
                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                i.putExtra("coordinatesLatitude", alerts.get(position).getCoordinates().getLatitude());
                i.putExtra("coordinatesLongitude", alerts.get(position).getCoordinates().getLongitude());
                i.putExtra("description", alerts.get(position).getDescription().toString());
                i.putExtra("busNumber", alerts.get(position).getBusNumber());

                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);

            }


        });
    }
}







public void getDataForListView(){
    final List<Alert> alerts = new ArrayList<Alert>();


    for (ParseObject alertParse : ob) {
            Alert alert = new Alert();
            alert.setBusNumber(alertParse.getInt("BusNumber"));
            alert.setCoordinates(alertParse.getParseGeoPoint("Coordinates"));
            alert.setCreatedAt(alertParse.getDate("createdAt"));
            alert.setDescription(alertParse.getString("Description"));

            alerts.add(alert);
    }



}
```

}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
//ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;
List<Alert> ob;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Alert> ob){

    this.context = context;
    this.ob = ob;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ob.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return ob.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null,false);
        holder.channel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelVariableLabel);
        holder.viewOnMap = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewOnMapVariableLabel);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionVariableLabel);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.channel.setText(ob.get(position).getBusNumber());
    holder.viewOnMap.setText("<Tap here to view alert on map>");
    holder.description.setText(ob.get(position).getDescription().toString());

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView channel;
    TextView viewOnMap;
    TextView description;
}
```

}

class Alert {

```
private int busNumber;
private ParseGeoPoint coordinates;
private Date createdAt;
private String description;

public Alert () {

}
public void setCreatedAt(java.util.Date date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}
public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}
public ParseGeoPoint getCoordinates() {
    return coordinates;
}
public void setCoordinates(ParseGeoPoint coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}
public int getBusNumber() {
    return busNumber;
}
public void setBusNumber(int busNumber) {
    this.busNumber = busNumber;
}
```

}

So please, almighty lords of Programming/Java/Android/Parse.com Users, lend this mortal a hand in finding his problem!

Thank you! Respects.

Comment: Use curl rest Ali to puts a couple rows out there in alerts. Change that name from "alertsclass" to something not ending in "class. Use parse browser to check your data is there on same name as your query and then retry.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. I did not understand the first part: "Use curl rest Ali to puts a couple rows out there in alerts.". I have no problems with the same app/database on Iphone/Windows phone, only on Android i have this error. The data in the query is correct, same names, populated.